# How to compile Typescript using Gulp and import/export statements (ts modules)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, browserify

I construct my project using Gulp and I use typescript files as modules. But I can not compile import/export statements. I get wrong js file and stack of errors in browser console.

I try an example from typescript.org/Gulp but it is not working. Maybe I doing something wrong.

code from tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "files": [
        "src/js/index.ts",
        "src/js/slider.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es2015"
    }
}
```

gulpfile.js:

```
const routes = {
    js: {
        dest: "dest/js/",
        build: "build/js/",
        watch: "src/js/**/*.ts"
    }
};

const prm = {
    browser: {
        server: "./dest",
        port: 3002
    }
    watch: {
        param: {
            ignoreInitial: false
        }
    }
};

const browser = require("browser-sync").create();
const {
    src,
    dest,
    series,
    parallel,
    watch
} = require("gulp");

function initBrowser(cb) {
    browser.init(prm.browser_build);
    cb();
}
function reload(cb) {
    browser.reload();
    cb();
}

function concat_js() {
    return browserify({
        basedir: '.',
        debug: true,
        entries: ['src/js/index.ts', 'src/js/slider.ts'],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {}
    })
        .plugin(tsify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(dest(routes.js.dest));
}

exports.default = function() {
    browser.init(prm.browser);
    watch(routes.js.watch, prm.watch.param, series(concat_js, reload));
};
```

index.ts:

```
import { Call } from "./slider";
function hello(compiler: string) {
    console.log(`Hello from ${compiler}`);
}
hello("TypeScript");
Call();
```

slider.ts:

```
export function Call() {
    console.log("running");
}
```

code from bundle.js:

```
(function(){function r(e,n,t){function o(i,f){if(!n[i]){if(!e[i]){var c="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!f&&c)return c(i,!0);if(u)return u(i,!0);var a=new Error("Cannot find module '"+i+"'");throw a.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",a}var p=n[i]={exports:{}};e[i][0].call(p.exports,function(r){var n=e[i][1][r];return o(n||r)},p,p.exports,r,e,n,t)}return n[i].exports}for(var u="function"==typeof require&&require,i=0;i<t.length;i++)o(t[i]);return o}return r})()({1:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var slider_1 = require("./slider");
function hello(compiler) {
    console.log("Hello from " + compiler);
}
hello("TypeScript");
slider_1.Call();

},{"./slider":2}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
function Call() {
    console.log("running");
}
exports.Call = Call;

},{}]},{},[1,2])

//# sourceMappingURL=bundle.js.map
```

and from target index.js:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var slider_1 = require("./slider");
function hello(compiler) {
    console.log("Hello from " + compiler);
}
hello("TypeScript");
slider_1.default();
```

Someone can help me with any hints or other ready solutions that using Gulp

Comment: Do you have to use gulp? The reason I ask is because v3 is deprecated and v4 just isn't as good as v3. I ended up moving to webpack because it couldn't transpile my exports and modules properly, the same issue you are also having. It was a bit of a learning curve but I am glad I did it.